# Error trying to install React-native-navigation packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Upon me instaling the packages of the react-navigation

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

I am getting this erorr

> No matching configuration of project :@react-native-community_masked-view was
> found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
> None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

for every package mentioned. What is the problem, and how could I fix it?